# Hover class not getting registered

Tags: html, css

I am not being able to use the hover class. Maybe it has got to do something with the absolute positioning done for creating the wave. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EB4C47;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 55%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  background: #EB4C47;
  width: 65%;
  height: 210px;
  top: 55px;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  height: 85px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar {
  margin-top: -150px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Courier New;
}

#box {
  /*background-color:rgb(104,137,117,0.7);*/
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: trparent;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#box:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 22px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 40%;
  height: 140px;
}

.head-box {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: linear-gradient();
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#title {
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
  <header id=header>
    <div id="header-container">
      <div id="header-img" class="head-box"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/putracetol/putracetol1808/putracetol180800251/106705685-cloth-logo-icon-design.jpg" alt="cloth-logo"></div>
      <div class="head-box" id="title">10X Clothing</div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-bar">
      <div id="box">Features</div>
      <div id="box">Quality</div>
      <div id="box">Pricing</div>
    </div>

  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with `id="box"`. `id` ***must be unique***. https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp If you need several identically styled elements, use a CSS `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `id` for multiple elements, `id` **must** be unique. You should change `box` to class and  remove `z-index` from `#wave`, you gave it -1 so all the child elements including `box` will inherit it and `box` will never get the hover event.

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EB4C47;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 55%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  background: #EB4C47;
  width: 65%;
  height: 210px;
  top: 55px;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  height: 85px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar {
  margin-top: -150px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Courier New;
}

.box {
  /*background-color:rgb(104,137,117,0.7);*/
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: trparent;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 22px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 40%;
  height: 140px;
}

.head-box {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: linear-gradient();
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#title {
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
  <header id=header>
    <div id="header-container">
      <div id="header-img" class="head-box"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/putracetol/putracetol1808/putracetol180800251/106705685-cloth-logo-icon-design.jpg" alt="cloth-logo"></div>
      <div class="head-box" id="title">10X Clothing</div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-bar">
      <div class="box">Features</div>
      <div class="box">Quality</div>
      <div class="box">Pricing</div>
    </div>

  </header>
</div>
```